# Live Edit in PhpStorm for Laravel projects

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I like to use Live Edit feature, however, it seems to me it only works with regular `.html` files, however, none of the known to me ways work with Laravel `.blade.php` files. Google didn't answer. 
Is there really no way to do so?

Comment: No, there isn't. Live Edit is limited to css,html & js: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/live-editing.html

Answer (score 6):

For Laravel projects, you can use [BrowserSync](https://browsersync.io/) to automatically refresh websites when you make changes to your template files. Support for BrowserSync comes out of the box with [Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/). To use this feature, all you have to do is go to your `webpack.mix.js` file and add the `mix.browserSync()` function call. If you're using Laravel Valet or something similar to get pretty URLs, you can pass in a URL as an argument to proxy.

```js
mix.browserSync();

// OR

mix.browserSync('my-domain.test');
```

Documentation: [Compiling Assets (Mix)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#browsersync-reloading)